# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Space Exploration Stack Exchange](http://space.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How hard is the Lunar surface?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/how-hard-is-the-lunar-surface)

  **Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Practical Lunar He-3 mining approach?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/practical-lunar-he-3-mining-approach)

  **Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 16, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is feathering?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/what-is-feathering)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How were vibrations supposed to be handled in an Ares I?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/how-were-vibrations-supposed-to-be-handled-in-an-ares-i)

  **Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Has America launched any satellites for Project Horizon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/has-america-launched-any-satellites-for-project-horizon)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the current cost-per-pound to send something into LEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/what-is-the-current-cost-per-pound-to-send-something-into-leo)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [How long did it take, at a minimum, to prep a shuttle for launch after it landed?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/how-long-did-it-take-at-a-minimum-to-prep-a-shuttle-for-launch-after-it-landed)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How will the RD-180 ban affect US space program?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/how-will-the-rd-180-ban-affect-us-space-program)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is LOI usually performed on the far side of Luna?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/is-loi-usually-performed-on-the-far-side-of-luna)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [What amendments were made to the Outer Space Treaty?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/what-amendments-were-made-to-the-outer-space-treaty)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 1):

All in my opinion:

### The good:

- We seem to have excellent activity overall
- The community seems, by what limited tools I have to make measurements, to be taking up the challenge of self-moderation quite well
- We have a decently steady flow of questions
- The mod team is doing an awesome job
- [Topic of the Week](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/topic-of-the-week-apollo-program?cb=1) is doing a great job of filling out the areas where the site lacks questions.

### The bad:

- Not enough answers per question, IMO (no, I'm not freaking out because of the A51 stats. This is just an observation I made)
- Maybe a little more editing is required (again IMO). See our [editors list](https://space.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors).

Comment: Agreed, and to add to it the activity levels on meta and the tags front went down as well. We still get suggested edits for tags every now and then but I think there's always room for improvement. And when we request to have our own blog, that'll be even more important (albeit also easier with some contents that can often be copied tit for tat from the blog to the tag main body). We're still missing at least short excerpts for a lot of tags tho.

Comment: @Undo What concerns do you have about the number of answers per question? In general, so long as the question is answered *well*, it's totally fine for it to just have one answer. Having too many answers per question can be indicative of other issues - such as questions where everyone can weigh in with an opinion rather than an answer or questions that are focused on just gathering a list of stuff.

Comment: @Anna In general, I'm noticing a reluctance to add another answer - even if the existing one is lacking. It might be a side effect of coming from (m)SO, but it seems that we could live with a few more answers on each question so that voting can have its effect. It's quite a minor concern, of course, which is indicative of an overall healthy site.

Comment: That sort of reluctance is a good thing to notice, although I think it's a slightly different problem than "not enough answers". My best advice at this point would be to lead by example and provide more complete answers if existing ones are deficient in some way.