# Space.SE resolution: 1000+ questions by year end

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, statistics

I would like all of us to make one rather reasonable resolution, to ask at least 1000 questions by New Year's Day 2014. This is a perfectly reasonable number to target, and should be close to our statistical projection based on last few months of activities. But with many  holidays coming up in between and activities of course dropping over those days, we should still probably step it up ever so slightly to reach it.

For example, to this day (Nov 2nd, 2013) we have asked 775 questions (the number on the right side of [this page](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)), which makes it in 110 days since the site was launched about 7 questions per day. Of course, that includes the private beta and first few weeks of public beta when new questions came in faster, and these statistics have by now, as expected, somewhat dropped. Our current projections stand at roughly 4 questions per day, and that should make us reach the presented goal of 1k questions in 56 days (rounding it down as I expect at least one more question being asked today). There are still 59 days left in this calendar year, so asking for 1000 questions by year's end should be reasonable. It is also a nice, fat, round number, and who doesn't like those as long as they're not on our tax report? What could be more suitable to quote as an achievement in a year that has passed? Ideally of course, we would reach this goal a lot sooner, and let's hope we indeed do.

Still, I wanted to take this opportunity to ask of all of you reading this and might have not asked many questions so far (me included, so this applies to me as well), to think if there is something you could change to result in more of interesting questions for the site, possibly with only a bit more of additional effort on your part. What I mean here is, that many of us might already be highly interested in the topics discussed on our site, follow daily events and news, read scientific journals, e.t.c. and stumble upon questions you might want to answer on your own, Google for something you've forgot about, refresh your memory. Well, do that a bit less on your own! :P Or, if you can't help yourself not to, ask and self-answer a question you still did research, and see what others make of it at the same time. Many seemingly trivial questions can result in highly interesting answers, even open up a whole world of new questions.

And if you don't know what to ask about, don't forget about our [Topic Of The Week (TOTW) scheme](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/49) we're running, and of course feel welcome to add new ideas there too, and vote on those you find most interesting so they are selected earlier and we build a healthy stack of questions about the topic.

Add if you have more ideas about increasing the number of questions faster while also keeping them as interesting as possible for the whole Space Exploration SE community (and of course on topic, e.t.c.), write your thoughts on all of this in a new answers below. Cheers!

Comment: Do we get Christmas gifts?

Comment: And on New Year's 2014, let's make a resolution to graduate by the end of 2015.

Comment: Also, I'll be active on holidays as long as I have an Internet connection :P

Comment: @Undo: That'll be hard, as there is at least a 6 month pipeline to graduating a site, so far as I can tell right now... IE, SE decides to graduate you, and 6 months later you will be graduated

Comment: @Manishearth: Most likely SE avatar hats;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### We can do it.