# Do we need a tag 'extra-terrestrial-minerals'?

Tags: discussion

At present [materials](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) is used in conjuction with an allied tag for mineral resources in more than one question

**For instance:**

[What source of raw materials could be found in space for making plastics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/what-source-of-raw-materials-could-be-found-in-space-for-making-plastics)

[What resources could be gained from asteroid mining that would be worth the effort?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/633/what-resources-could-be-gained-from-asteroid-mining-that-would-be-worth-the-effo)

[Does Mars contain materials that could be used to build a space colony?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/614/does-mars-contain-materials-that-could-be-used-to-build-a-space-colony)

I propose a new [extra-terrestrial-minerals](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extra-terrestrial-minerals) to clean-up the materials tag.

Thoughts, anybody?

Answer (score 2):

**I'm against creating another, somewhat too specific tag [extra-terrestrial-minerals](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extra-terrestrial-minerals) while we still haven't utilized slightly broader tag [minerals](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minerals), previously [proposed](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/457/49) in one of our earlier [Topic of The Week](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/452/49).**

I think that the problem stems from improper or insufficient tagging of those questions, not that we need another tag. We already have [natural-resources](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-resources) that seems to have been missed in those three cases. Here's what I propose:

- The [first](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/what-source-of-raw-materials-could-be-found-in-space-for-making-plastics) and the [third](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/614/does-mars-contain-materials-that-could-be-used-to-build-a-space-colony) question in your list could use both [materials](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) and [natural-resources](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-resources) tags, since they're asking about natural resources as well as [in-situ resource utilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-situ_resource_utilization) to produce certain synthetic materials. The third one could also use the [construction](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction) tag.
- The [second](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/633/what-resources-could-be-gained-from-asteroid-mining-that-would-be-worth-the-effo) question should be re-tagged to use [natural-resources](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-resources) instead of [materials](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials).

How does that sound?

---

**Update**: I went ahead and added the suggested tags to those three questions mentioned. ;)

Comment: Seems reasonable. Fwiw it may be good to have e-t-minerals as a synonym for nat-res too. When I looked for minerals, the alternative term nat-res didn't come to mind at all (+; but that may be because I'm not a native English speaker (typer?)